# Range of 1 volt radio wave

Tags: voltage, radio, wave

I have a simple question how much radio wave produced by 1 VOLT can reach in KM , i mean it will be detectable in which range , without any mountains walls ..etc just on flat surface with air?

Comment: Depending on things you did not specify it could be anywhere from a few meters to many km. Here are a few things you did not specify: 1) Why you are asking the question. 2) frequency. 3) antenna type or gain. 4) Type of signal (because some types of signal are much more recoverable even at very low SNR). There may be more things you didn't specify that are relevant to the question. But antenna type is the big one. A good antenna can really boost range. If both sides have good antennas that is even better.

Comment: Read this to see if it can help you improve your question:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_budget

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_(electronics)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss

Comment: This is too broad to fit with the mission of SE sites.  Generally, the issue is not transmit power, but a viable propagation path (which you have), interference (unknown), antennas (unknown) and receiver (unknown).  As several have pointed out, you also fail to say what impedance this volt is across, so you haven't actually stated a power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given 0.632vpp is 0dBm (i.e. exactly 1 milliWatt) across 50 ohms, we'll use that power level. What distance, for 0dB SNR (good for Morse Code) in 10Hertz bandwidth? At 30 MHz (near the CB allocation)? With quarterwave antenna?

The required energy from the receiver antenna is

-174 dBm/rtHz

+10dB for 10Hertz BW (good for several dit/dah per second)

+0 dB  SignalNoiseRatio

+0 dB noise figure of receiver, and any matching loses

---

total -174 + 10 = -164dBm; -160 is 10^-8 volts below 0.632vpp or 6.32 nanoVolts.
We have -164dBm or 6.32nanovolt/sqrt(2.5) = 5 nanoVolts peakpeak.

The total path loss 164dB, line-of-sight, no antenna losses or multipathing.
[read Andy answer for more details on realworld problems]

Path Loss is 22 dB + 10 * log10([distance/wavelength] ^2 )

Our allocation for distance/wavelength is 10^[(164-22)/20] = 10^142/20 = 10^7.1

Thus distance can be 10^7.1 times one wavelength.

Lambda (30MHz) is 10meters, thus distance can be 100,000,000 meters 
or 100,000 kilometers. 30Mhz is good frequency for long range RF communication.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean 1 \$V_{RMS}\$ feeding a dipole antenna. Your question is lacking substance so some assumptions do have to be made.

Next, the electrical impedance presented by a dipole antenna at the optimum operating frequency (approximately half \$\lambda\$) is about 74 ohms hence, the power you are delivering into the antenna is \$1^2\$/74 = 13.5 mW or about 11 dBm.

Again there is an assumption here that your driving frequency is optimized for the half \$\lambda\$ wavelength of a dipole antenna.

In free space (not on a flat earthy surface) the loss between a transmitting isotropic antenna and a receiving isotropic antenna is: -

Loss (dB) = 32.45 + 20\$log_{10}\$(f) + 20\$log_{10}\$(d)

Where f is in MHz and d is in kilometres. This equation tells you how many dB of power loss you can expect at a given distance with a given carrier frequency.

So if your dipole is 0.5m long you would drive it with a frequency that has a \$\lambda\$ of 1 metre. This is of course 300 MHz but, you also need to estimate how much power your receiver needs to adequately decipher the received transmission and the following formula is generally accepted as being accurate: -

Power needed at ambient temperatures is -154 dBm + 10\$log_{10}\$(data rate).

This is related to the formula in analogsystemsrf's answer but gives a 20 dB margin in signal to noise ratio to allow for reasonably low bit error rates. So here is another assumption - I'm assuming that the background to your question is related to digital data transmission and reception. For analogue signals, you may be happy with a smaller SNR such as 10 dB.

If you transmit at 10 bits per second and your receiving antenna delivers at least -144 dBm to your receiver circuit you will be reasonably OK. However, this is in free-space and, here on earth (or the flat surface mentioned in the question), it's a good idea to add back in another 30 dB of signal to account for fade losses.

So, realistically, at 10 bits per second you should expect to deliver -114 dBm to the receiver AND the receiver has to be designed to have a tight bandwidth that excludes wideband thermal noise and other potential interferers. You should also choose a transmit carrier frequency that is very accurate and does not significantly move more than a few Hz.

So, to summarize, we know: -

- The transmit power
- The link loss equation
- The required receive power

Given the several assumptions made, you can plug the numbers into online calculators such as [this one here](https://www.everythingrf.com/rf-calculators/free-space-path-loss-calculator): -

[image]

I have entered a couple of other parameters namely transmitting and receiving antenna gains. I have used 2 dB for both meaning that a dipole antenna has approximately 2 dB more gain that an isotropic antenna.

The path loss is 117 dB so if you transmit 11 dBm you will receive -106 dBm and this is a few dB better than the calculated receiver signal required for 10 bits per second data of -114 dBm so...

100 km should be OK at 300 MHz but, remember, that is in a straight line and the curvature of the earth means that to get a 100 km line of sight needs both antennas lifted up to 150 m in height. Go find a calculator that works out line of sight. There are several on google.

Comment: Yes, you possibly do. Nobody said radio was easy and nobody said that a well-though-out accurate answer with most of the facts embodied and a link to a path loss calculator gets formal acceptance.

Comment: @ Andy They can have the one-page answer which ignores the antennas and other (propagation) losses, or they can read your detailed answer. In teaching this kind of system-design mindset, both simple and complete explanations are valuable; thank you for providing the full range of issues.